# How Euler get $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Tags: real-analysis

I saw on [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probl%C3%A8me_de_B%C3%A2le) that he consider $$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}+...$$

The roots are given by $x=\pm n\pi$ and thus (to me)
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=(x-\pi)(x+\pi)(x-2\pi)(x+2\pi)(x-3\pi)(x+3\pi)...$$

How can he get
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\left(1-\frac{x}{2\pi}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{2\pi}\right)\left(1-\frac{x}{3\pi}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{3\pi}\right)...\ \ \ ??$$

Comment: The leading coefficient is missing in your expansion. Evaluate the LHS at e.g. $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to find it.

Comment: See Titcmarch's book: Theory of functions and use of residues. They are there and much more.

Comment: One is tempted to surmise that $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}} x-n\pi = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}} 1-\frac{x}{n\pi}$ simply because the two polynomials share all the same roots... is this sufficient?

Comment: @LJL: It's not clear how $\prod (x-n\pi)$ could converge unless $x=n\pi$ for some integer $n$. Otherwise, for fixed $x$, the factors grow without bound (and the signs eventually oscillate). On the other hand, the factors of $\prod (1 - x/(n\pi))$, converge to $1$ for fixed $x$ as $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Euler's proof is a bit adhoc. He uses the fact that for finite polynomials if:

$$(x-r_1)\dots(x-r_n)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0$$

then $$\dfrac{1}{r_1}+\dots+\dfrac{1}{r_n}=\dfrac{-a_1}{a_0}$$

Then he assumes the result is true for power series, and uses:

$$\dfrac{\sin(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}=1-\dfrac{x}{3!}+\dfrac{x^2}{5!}+\dots$$

so $r_k=(k\pi)^2$ and $a_0=1$ and $a_1=\dfrac{-1}{6}$.

[Reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC8QFjACahUKEwio2IbWk8fHAhWGF9sKHeBhCpY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maa.org%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fpdf%2Fupload_library%2F22%2FPolya%2F07468342.di020759.02p00026.pdf&ei=T-fdVej0EYav7Abgw6mwCQ&usg=AFQjCNEy-VDFnSf26P9lc8W8Xhnw7rx0Sw&sig2=fRZh-oUeO_oijhR2hhUtgQ&cad=rja)